# relay to external network smtp server using sendmail as mta

Tags: linux, redhat, sendmail

I am banging my head on desk for this.
My linux system is on local network where as my smtp server is on different network.
Is there any way that I can relay mails from my local machine to this remote smtp server to send mails ?
My apologies if I sound stupid or if it's very easy to do so. :(

Here is what I have done so far: 
setup my local machine to send outbound mails by setting 
SMART_HOST as my smtp server ( smtp.xxx.com ) in sendmail.cf
but i guess this exercise works when relaying for hosts on internal networks.
And my smtp server ( smtp.xxx.com ) is on external network to my local machine.
Do I need to update my sendmail configuration to relay to external network?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it:

- Configure an actual SMTP relay.
- Use a VPN.
- Use an ssh port forwarding.

The quickest to get started with is the ssh port forwarding, which in its simplest form could look like this: `ssh -f -N -L '25:[::1]:25' -o ExitOnForwardFailure=true user@host.example.com`

It is not the most reliable solution, as the ssh connection can die for a number of different reasons. More detailed advice would require more knowledge about your network. For example we would need to know, why the clients cannot connect directly to the SMTP server on the other network.

Comment: Thanks kasperd for the quick turnaround. Here I can't use vpn for some issue and don't wanna go with ssh forwarding, however can you please explain pt#1 actual SMTP relay.  Also please look at my updated question above. Thanks

Comment: @ankidaemon You still haven't told us, why you can't have the client connect directly to the remote SMTP server. Until we know that, we can't say if you can overcome that limitation by running your own relay.